# Cómo insertar una secuencia de comandos (script) en el nuevo Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

A finales del año pasado Google lanzó al público el nuevo Google Sites. En el Google Sites Clásico es posible insertar secuencias de comandos. Ya revisé el centro de ayuda y los blogs de oficiales de Google en inglés y en español y no encuentro cómo hacer lo mismo.

Fuentes consultadas:

- [Centro de Ayuda de Google Sites](https://support.google.com/sites?hl=es)
- [A totally rebuilt Sites, customer-tested and open for business](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/totally-rebuilt-sites-customer-tested/) (Artículo sobre el lanzamiento del nuevo Google Sites para usuarios y administradores de G Suite)
- [Esto es Google - Blog oficial de Google en español](https://tecnologiayproductosgoogle.blogspot.mx/)

Comment: La idea de esta pregunta es "inaugurar" la etiqueta de Google Sites. Mas tarde publicaré la respuesta, pero si alguien más está interesado en colaborar, más que bienvenido.

Comment: Publicada la versión inicial de la respuesta que tenía pensado agregar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien el nuevo Google Sites ya se graduó del "Early Adopter Program (EAP)", el cual es un programa por medio del cual Google invita a algunos usuarios de [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/es-419/) a probar nuevos productos y servicios, las funciones que incluye actualmente son las que podríamos llamar como mínimas. Esto con base en el enunciado siguiente tomado de [A totally rebuilt Sites, customer-tested and open for business](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/totally-rebuilt-sites-customer-tested/)

> Customers can continue to use classic Sites as we continue to add capabilities and improve the new Sites.

Traducción: Los clientes pueden continuar usando Sites Clásico mientras continuamos agregando capacidades y mejoramos el nuevo Sites.

Más información:

- [Getting Started: classic vs. new Sites](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/NXcBWrvLq2c), publicación en el [Foro oficial de Google Sites en inglés](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/sites)
- [Google Sites Classic Comparison](http://www.steegle.com/google-sites/classic-comparison), incluye una tabla donde se listan las funciones de ambas versiones de Sites.